# Apollo GraphQL Queries in React Apps

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

Hey I am just starting to learn GraphQL for React, and Full Stack Applications and looking at Apollo and wondering why in my React.js I would right a query in graphqls query language instead of the json format?

Example Apollo React wants

```
query: gql`
      query GetRates {
        rates(currency: "USD") {
          currency
        }
      }
    `
```

but on the server, you can write

```
{
  books {
    title
    author
  }
}
```

Why can't I write the second in my React application? Am I missing something, is there a better React GraphQL client to use?

Comment: That isn't JSON, its just a GraphQL shorthand. I wouldn't say that there is a better client, but using [codegen](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/) and having queries automatically made into hooks has been a huge time saver for me on projects. It can also make TS bindings for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [GraphQL docs](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/).

The following is a shorthand where you omit both the query keyword and the query name:

```
{
  books {
    title
    author
  }
}
```

It is the same as:

```
query getBooks {
  books {
    title
    author
  }
}
```

`gql` from `apollo-client` employs additional logic to parse GraphQL strings. Think about query parameters for example.